# Placeholder position when input has text

Tags: css, webkit

How to do placeholder styling when Input Text are focus, the placeholder are still visible and the font-size become smaller. For example like this:

[image]

I only need webkit support. Does webkit support such thing?

Comment: This will need to be a custom element. The term for this is "floating labels", I'm sure you can find more information online and ask another question if you run into problems implementing a certain technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  outline:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.label { position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
input:focus ~ .label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .label{
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="input" required/>
  <span class="label">Company Name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `label` element and modify it accordingly. Try this:

```js
function fillClass() {
  if ($(this).val() != '')
    $(this).parent().addClass('input--filled');
  else
    $(this).parent().removeClass('input--filled');
}


$(".sign-in-input").focusout(fillClass);
```

```css
.sign-in-input-ctr {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.sign-in-input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.sign-in-input:focus,
.input--filled .sign-in-input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #a09e9e;
}
.sign-in-label {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 15px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.sign-in-input:focus+.sign-in-label,
.input--filled .sign-in-label {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-15px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign-in-input-ctr">
  <input class="sign-in-input" type="text" name="email">
  <label class="sign-in-label" for="signin-email"><span class="input-label-content">Email</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//------ contact us dropdown list
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".form-group .form-control" ).focus(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('inputFous');
}).blur(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == '')
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('inputFous');  
    }       
});
});
```

I think there is no webkit support for this, please check this code which will help you:- [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az82gt0u/)